# Upload Shiny application via Amazon Web Services (AWS)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny

Is there any method to publish Shiny application by Amazon Web Services (AWS).

I have not ever use AWS.

---

**Edit after comments**

Thank you for every comments, it would help me, but it needs time for me to try them. I will read all pages (movie) give in comments or answer.

Now, I try to upload Shiny in which the rstan is used.
The most simple code will be as following;

```
library(shiny);library(Rcpp);library(rstan);

 ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("An example Shiny code including rstan package, which requires a lot of RAM"),

   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

 server <- function(input, output) {


  fit <- shiny::reactive({

    model <- rstan::stan_model(
      model_code = "parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(0,1);}            "
    )

    fit <- rstan::sampling(model)

    return(fit)

  })


  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    rstan::stan_hist(fit(),bins=input$bins)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If someone can success to upload the above shiny script including rstan, then please let me know.

The usual way using Shiny server will fail since it require more than 1 Gb RAM, which should pay money and my credit card was declined, so I cannot up grade the RAM.

Comment: Hope this helps https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-host-a-r-shiny-app-on-aws-cloud-in-7-simple-steps-5595e7885722

Comment: Have you seen: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/video_guide.html already? No need to install r and shiny and sample apps are already running on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to deploy a shiny application on AWS.

1. Part 1: Create a Shiny app.
2. Part 2: Create an AWS server.
3. Part 3: Install R and R Shiny on your new server.
4. Part 4: Deploy the app on the server.
5. Part 5: Create a nice domain name.

[image]

You can explore further [shiny-aws](https://www.charlesbordet.com/en/shiny-aws-4/#) and [running-r-on-aws](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/)